# Can not able to add foreign key in my table using H2 database

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, h2

I have been trying to add a foreign key to my table studentJobInformation.
I have two tables[image] applicationForm which is having a column versityId. I want to make this as my foreign key to this studentJobInformation table. But unfortunately, I could not do that. First image shows the information of the column of applicationForm table and second image shows the studentJobInformation
enter image description here
then I write this SQL to add Foreign key.

***ALTER TABLE studentJobInformation ADD FOREIGN KEY (versityId) REFERENCES applicationForm((versityId)***

But my H2 database shows this error.

*Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE STUDENTJOBINFORMATION ADD FOREIGN KEY (VERSITYID) REFERENCES APPLICATIONFORM(([*]VERSITYID) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE studentJobInformation ADD FOREIGN KEY (versityId) REFERENCES applicationForm((versityId) [42001-196] 42001/42001*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have two opening parentheses before `versityId` at the end of the command, you need to remove one.

Comment: @Evgenjij Thank you for your hard work. That is what happens to me when I work late at night. I have gone through at least 20 times but could not find this error. But unfortunately, It did not work either. I just removed the (versityId) from the end and it works. My SQl is like this now """ ALTER TABLE studentJobInformation ADD FOREIGN KEY (versityId) REFERENCES applicationForm; """". I do not know why this working. Maybe H2 database knows what is the primary key of applicationForm table.

Comment: You need to use `ALTER TABLE STUDENTJOBINFORMATION ADD FOREIGN KEY (VERSITYID) REFERENCES APPLICATIONFORM(VERSITYID)`. You can omit `(VERSITYID)` after `REFERENCES APPLICATIONFORM`, but in that case a primary key column (`APPLICATIONID`) will be used, I guess it isn't your intention. Your schema, however, looks suspicious, normally you shouldn't reference secondary keys in referential constraints, but it's another question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your last comment is eye-opening for me. I was wrong from the beginning. I need to change my schema and have to restructure my tables.